# how to access child instances in a vector in c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, parent

I have a parent class and child class (inherited from parent).
In the child class, I have a member function named `function_blah();`

I used `vector<parent*> A` to store 5 parent instances, 3 child instances. So the total number of elements in the vector is 8.

I can easily access to member functions of element A[0] to A[4], which are parent instances.
But whenever I try to have access to member functions of element A[5] to A[7], the compiler complains that `class parent has no member named 'function_blah'`

The way I access to elements is using index. e.x A[i] with i = 0..7. Is it correct? if not, how?

Comment: Your question is incomplete : what are the relations between the classes `parent` and the child class?

Comment: child class inherits from parent class

Comment: He says, "I have a parent class and child class (inherited from parent)." I think the relationship is clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to downcast the pointer to the child class in order to use child functions on it.

When you're accessing a child object using a `parent*`, you are effectively telling the compiler, "treat this object as a `parent`". Since `function_blah()` only exists on the child, the compiler doesn't know what to do.

You can ameliorate this by *downcasting* using the `dynamic_cast` operator:

```
child* c = dynamic_cast<child*>(A[6]);
c->function_blah();
```

This will perform a runtime-checked, type-safe cast from the `parent*` to a `child*` where you can call `function_blah()`.

This solution only works if you *know* that the object you're pulling out is definitely a `child` and not a `parent`. If there's uncertainty, what you need to do instead is use inheritance and create a virtual method on the parent which you then overload on the child.

Comment: Thank you very much for you suggestions. I'll use the virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

You're storing parent*, which has no function_blah method. You need to either make function_blah a virtual method of parent, or use dynamic_cast to downcast to a child*.

Answer (score 0):

Is member `_blah()` declared virtual in `parent`? Or is it even declared in `parent`? Because if not, then you'll never be able to access `_blah()` through a parent pointer. And yes, you'll also have to downcast, but only if you know exactly that you're expecting a `child` type.